# SQL Large Table select random row strategy

Tags: sql-server, select

I would like to select a random row from a very large table (10 mil records). So the strategy that are most common such as `RAND()` and `NEWID()` doesn't seem to be practical.

I have tried the following strategy and would like to know if this is the most ideal way.

1. Create a new field called 'RandomSort' as UniqueIdentified
2. At the end of each hour/day will do a `Update RandomSort = NewID()` to the entire table
3. Each time I need to query, I can do a `Top 10 Order by RandomSort`

It does get the job done (better than `ORDER BY NewID`), but not sure if this is the best practice so far?

Comment: Does the table have a integer primary key?

Comment: Why do you say that `RAND()` and `NEWID()` is impractical?

Comment: It seems to be good. But doesn't the UPDATE stress too much the DB?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the primary key has to be UniqueIdentifier :(

Comment: Rand() and NewID() strategy is very very slow to run on a large table. For Small table it's perfect. No question.

Comment: Yeah, it does stress the DB quite a bit. But at least it happens once an hour/day. Rather than every single query (which is a lot) probably 1-2 queries per second.

Comment: @Lasker, why you are updating db in the evening? Just give a default value to new column ...

Comment: Reason to update in the evening, I need random rows. If the RandomSort field is not updated hourly/daily, then it will never be random :)

Comment: is there a clustered index on the table already?

Comment: Yes, it is on the UniqueIdentifier of that table.

Comment: Here is a great way to get a random sample from a large table: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an identity column 'rowid' (`int` or `bigint` depending on your table size) and create a unique non-clustered index on it.

The following query uses the `NEWID()` function to return approximately one percent of the rows of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), rowID) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
```

The rowId column is included in the CHECKSUM expression so that NEWID() evaluates once per row to achieve sampling on a per-row basis. The expression `CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), rowid) & 0x7fffffff AS float / CAST(0x7fffffff AS int)` evaluates to a random float value between 0 and 1.

In fact you could use any column indexed column in your table (I believe).

If you just want to pick a single random row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table 
WHERE rowid >= RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM table)
```

This works in constant time, provided the `rowid` column is indexed. Note: this assumes that `rowid` is uniformly distributed in the range `0..MAX(rowid)`, hence the suggested identity column addition. If your dataset has some other distribution, your results will be skewed (i.e. some rows will be picked more often than others).

Comment: Will give this a try. Thanks.
Question: The method I mentioned above will do a full table scan right? While your method doesn't?